# Create automation rule when receiving email in Outlook to connect to external Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have created a custom access database of contacts.  I would like to connect Outlook to the database, so that every time a user receives an e-mail, an action is triggered that searches the access database to see if that contact exists (based on the e-mail address I guess).  If the contact doesn't exist, it offers to automatically add the contact to the database using information from the e-mail, and then add the contents of the e-mail as an information note to that contact.  If the contact does exist, it automatically adds the content of the e-mail as an information note to the existing contact.

Can anyone guide me on how I could set such a system up?  I am used to developing in MS Access with VBA, but I'm not used to developing in Outlook with VBA, so I'm not sure where to begin.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason this needs to be done in Access as opposed to the extensive built-in support for contact management in Outlook?

Comment: It needs to be done in Access because the database also holds details of courses that people are on and their related payments.

Answer (score 1):

It is a while since I tested this, but it is possible to use Outlook events.

For this example you will need a Class Module called clsOlMail with this code:

```
'Requires reference to the Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library
Dim WithEvents conItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set oApp = Outlook.Application
   Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set conFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
   Set conItems = conFolder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set conItems = Nothing
   Set conFolder = Nothing
   Set oNS = Nothing
   Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ConItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim frm As Form

   Set frm = Forms!frmEmailDetails

   frm.txtSenderName = Item.SenderName
   frm.txtSentOn = Item.SentOn
   frm.txtTo = Item.To
   frm.txtCreationTime = Item.CreationTime
   frm.txtBCC = Item.BCC
   frm.txtCC = Item.CC
   frm.txtSentOnBehalfOfName = Item.SentOnBehalfOfName
   frm.txtSubject = Item.Subject
   frm.txtBody = Item.Body
End Sub
```

You will also need a form called frmEmailDetails with these textboxes:

```
txtSenderName, 
txtSentOn, 
txtTo, 
txtCreationTime, 
txtBCC, 
txtCC, 
txtSentOnBehalfOfName, 
txtSubject, 
txtBody
```

And this code:

```
Private oEvent As clsOLMail
'Requires reference to Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library

Public oApp As Outlook.Application
Public oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Public conFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Set oEvent = New clsOlMail
End Sub
```

Open the form and send an email through Outlook, you can use one of the examples shown above. The form fields should fill with the relevant details from the sent email. You are likely to get an Outlook security warning.

Comment: Hi Remou, thank you very much for your answer. It is very helpful and gives me something to work from.